# cannot import name "Contact"

Tags: python, mysql, django, web-applications, directory-structure

I am trying to develop my first Django application, this is my directory tree:

```
demo-project
|____(html)
|____(myproject)
    |___db_dump.sql
    |___manage.py
    |___(myapp)
    |   |___(templates)
    |   |___ __init__.py
    |   |___ forms.py
    |   |___ models.py
    |   |___ tests.py
    |   |___ views.py
    |
    |___(myproject)
        |___ __init__.py
        |___ settings.py
        |___ urls.py
        |___ wsgi.py
```

And here are my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.forms import mwa_event_form


class mwa_user(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birthday = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    fbIdUser = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    os = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Contact(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sender = models.EmailField(max_length=100)


class mwa_event_model(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = mwa_event_form
        fields = ['bfirstName', 'blastName']
```

and forms.py

```
from myapp.models import Contact
from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    sender = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)


class mwa_user_form(forms.Form):
    unique_id = forms.IntegerField()
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=75)
    firstName = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastName = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    gender = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    birthday = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    fbIdUser = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    os = forms.CharField(max_length=30)


class mwa_event_form(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['bfirstName', 'blastName']
```

when I try to issue the command `python manage.py runserver` I get warned by the following:

```
File "/var/lib/stickshift/51e9c62e500446b4bf0000e0/approot/data/563815/myproject/myapp/models.py", line 3, in <module>  
from myapp.forms import mwa_event_form 

File "/var/lib/stickshift/51e9c62e500446b4bf0000e0/approot/data/563815/myproject/myapp/forms.py", line 1, in <module>
from myapp.models import Contact

ImportError: cannot import name Contact
```

What am I missing? I read in similar posts that this could be related to a circular dependency, but I did not really get what this means looking at the Django documentation. Is this related to the directory folders structure?

Comment: models.py imports forms.py and forms.py imports models.py. That's what a circular import is.

Comment: Yeah, this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  put your `mwa_event_model` from `models.py` into your `forms.py` file as it is a form. This will fix the circular import noticed in @Wooble's answer.

As a side-note, perhaps you should read the python style guide "PEP8" for the [naming convention of classes](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).

**Edit:** I accidentally wrote `mwa_event_form` in my initial answer.

Comment: That resolves the problem of the circular import,but I cannot use mwa_event_form to define my mwa_event_model in the following :       class mwa_event_model(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = mwa_event_form
        fields = ['bfirstName', 'blastName']

Comment: That should be in your `forms.py` file. `ModelForm` is a type of form.

Comment: It solved the problem, but still I'm not able to access my index.html, also if I guess it is not related to the problem you solved but to my mapping in urls.py : Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^myapp/$
^myapp/book_list
^myapp/pictures_for_user
^admin/doc/
^admin/
^myapp/add_item [name='bevolist-add-item']
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

Comment: Perhaps you should open a new question.